# Post a Model with Collection reference to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model that has a properties as name, email... etc. Also has a Collection. 
In the View I edit the properties and I kept the Collection UNchanged.

When I try to submit the form, it sends the changed and unchaged values, BUT the Collection is lost. How to handle this?

`HTML.HiddenFor()` - doesn't work.

It loses all proprties that are not changed  in the form !(In the form I use `HTML.EditorFor(Model => Model.Name)`)

Edit: 
View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
       {%>
    <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name: </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Name) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone: </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Phone) %></td>
        </tr>
@h@</table>
    <%} %>
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SaveModelDealer(User ModelReceived)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                        using (Context db = new Context ())
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" " + ModelReceived.ListOfPhones.Count);
                        }
                        return View();
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just retrieve it in the Controller like you did in the first place.

Comment: It gives me NullReference Exception, when I do that.

Comment: I mean populate the collection from a database etc.

Comment: I use Ado.net Entitiy Data Model. So I can't just get the Collection

Comment: Using `Model` as a lambda variable name isn't a good idea, I think. It might conflict with `WebViewPage.Model`. Try renaming it to something like `model`, or `m`. Also, what are you trying to accomplish in the controller?

Comment: To save an obejct to DataBase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only properties inside a form are send back to the server with a post. You should re-populate the collection after the post the same way you did in the `HttpGet` action.

If you want to persist items in the form, but not show them, you can use a hidden field. Like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID);
```

Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703958/persist-selectlist-in-model-on-post/18704143), I gave an example to solve your problem.

Comment: I also have an object reference. How to deal with it and the values that are not changed?

Comment: If I use your method I will get the data that is not changed, but I also need the ID of the Model which is not changed.

Comment: Updated by answer, does that help you?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want this data to be displayed on the user side. I don't want to be shown in the rendered form in the hidden field, because is shows the value of the ID.

Comment: But I want to persist the ID, in the obejct itself - not in the hidden field

Comment: There is no such thing as 'object' in HTML, every property you want to persist, must be in the form. It's MVC who creates an object with the properties specified in the form for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: You're welcome. Tip: you can create a second hidden field, containing the id, but then in an hashed form. After the post you can hash the posted id and check if it matches with the previously hashed id.