# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key country

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

While binding dropdown in MVC, I always get this error: `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key country`.

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("country", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countrydrop,"Select country")
```

**Controller**

```
List<Companyregister> coun = new List<Companyregister>();
coun = ds.getcountry();

List<SelectListItem> item8 = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach( var c in coun )
{
    item8.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = c.country,
        Value = c.countryid.ToString()
    });
}

ViewBag.countrydrop = item8;
return View();
```

I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: i have updated my code check it.

Comment: If you are getting this error, then it means that the value of `ViewBag.coutrydrop` is `null`. Either the code for populating it is not being executed, or this is only occurring when you post back and return the view (and you have not populated `ViewBag.countrydrop` again)

Comment: And consider simplifying your code to `ViewBag.countrydrop = new SelectList(coun, "countryid", "country");` and `@Html.DropDownList("country",(SelectList)ViewBag.countrydrop, ...)`

Comment: If your open the demo in the accepted answer, and change `ViewBag.country = item8;` to `ViewBag.countrydrop = item8;` and `@Html.DropDownList("country","Select country")` to `@Html.DropDownList("country",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countrydrop,"Select country")` i.e. as per your posted code you will see that it also works. The issue is not the naming, its the fact that the ViewBag property is `null` which you can test by now changing `ViewBag.countrydrop = item8;` to `ViewBag.countrydrop = null;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke YA dude ur right its null and how to populate it

Comment: Is the error happening in the initial load, or just when you post back and return the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke happening in intial load

Comment: Since `ViewBag.countrydrop` must be null, all I can suggest is you debug and step through your code to find out why

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your action change  `ViewBag.countrydrop = item8` to `ViewBag.country = item8;`and in View write like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("country",
                   (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country,
                   "Select country")
```

Actually when you write

> > **@Html.DropDownList("country",
> >                            (IEnumerable)ViewBag.country,
> >                            "Select country")**

or

> > **Html.DropDownList("country","Select Country)**

it looks in for `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in `ViewBag` with key **country**, you can also use this overload in this case:

```
@Html.DropDownList("country","Select country") // it will look for ViewBag.country and populates dropdown
```

See [Working DEMO Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0cAyQv)

Comment: nice Sajjad, _perhaps_ first time seeing a dotnet fiddle for _MVC !!_..

Comment: @Irf there is always a first time for everything!!

Answer (score 27):

If you were using `DropDownListFor` like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItemId, Model.MySelectList)
```

where `MySelectList` in the model was a property of type `SelectList`, this error could be thrown if the property was `null`.

Avoid this by simply initializing it in constructor, like this:

```
public MyModel()
{
    MySelectList = new SelectList(new List<string>()); // empty list of anything...
}
```

This often happens in `POST` actions. Make sure you assign something before **re-rendering** the view.

Comment: Or something like this:
MySelectList  = new List<SelectListItem>();

Comment: Way too common scenario: error happens on POST, so you return the view model to the page with an error. But you didn't refresh the List<SelectListItem>'s which were lost in the POST - so they're null. Instead of a null-ref, get a really misleading error from the View saying that some property is not of a particular type when you know full well it's not supposed to be of that type etc

Comment: @mmcrae exactly, I had this problem a couple of times with POST action, where I forgot to populate my dropdown items again.

Comment: The comment "property was null" was key, indicating the viewbag item did not get populated for some reason.

Comment: This fix may not work for most of the issues as this code makes list empty, which means that after postback, your dropdown list becomes empty, and hence you cannot insert second record. I upvoted by mistake, and now I am unable revoke my vote.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if the error just said "MySelectList is null".

Comment: @Ashokkumar the empty list is just to avoid the misleading error message. You're right that you would get an empty dropdown after postback, but hey, at least you'd have a hint that you forgot to repopulate your model during postback, as opposed to the weird exception message you get otherwise.

Comment: @SteveSmith haha why making it simple when you can make it complex, right? :)

Answer (score 4):

Note that a select list is posted as null, hence your error complains that the viewdata property cannot be found.

Always reinitialize your select list within a POST action.

For further explanation:
[Persist SelectList in model on Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703958/persist-selectlist-in-model-on-post)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlcountry",(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countrydrop,"Select country")
```

In Controller

```
ViewBag.countrydrop = ds.getcountry().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.country, Value = x.countryid.ToString() }).ToList();
```

Comment: are you able to get countries in your list?

Comment: @dazzling kumar change your dropdownlist name.I have updated my code check it and change your DropDownList name in view `country` instead of `ddlcountry` then its works.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

Controller:

```
List<CountryModel> countryList = db.countryTable.ToList();
ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(countryList, "Country", "CountryName");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
 var list = new SelectList(countryList, "Id", "Name");
 ViewBag.countries=list;
 @Html.DropDownList("countries",ViewBag.countries as SelectList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same problem and I found the solution that I should put the code to retrieve the drop down list from database in the Edit Method. It worked for me.
[Solution for the similar problem](https://forums.asp.net/t/1792704.aspx?There%20is%20no%20ViewData%20item%20of%20type%20IEnumerable%20SelectListItem%20that%20has%20the%20key%20JobCodeType%20)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error occurred because I had not initialized the select list in the controller like this:

```
viewModel.MySelectList = new List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
```

As none of the existing answers made this clear to me, I post this. Perhaps it helps anybody.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct because in some cases it does not work, I also do not know where the error comes from but this can help you solve the problem, move the code in the head of the view like this:

```
index.cshtml:

@using expert.Models;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    Manager db = new Manager();
    ViewBag.FORM_PRESTATION = new SelectList(db.T_BDE_PRESTATION_PRES.OrderBy(p => p.PRES_INTITULE).Where(p => p.T_B_PRES_ID == null), "PRES_ID", "PRES_INTITULE");

}


<div class="form-group">                    
<label class = "w3-blue" style ="text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #444">Domaine:</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
 @Html.DropDownList("FORM_PRESTATION", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "w3-select ", @required = "true" })
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"country"` with `"countrydrop"` in your view like this...

```
@Html.DropDownList("countrydrop", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countrydrop,"Select country")
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could be like for ASP.NET MVC Framework

```
@Html.DropDownList("country", ViewBag.countrydrop as List<SelectListItem>,"Select country")
```

or ASP.NET Core MVC

```
<select class="class" id="country"
asp-items="@(new SelectLits(ViewBag.countrydrop,"Value","Text"))">
```

Answer (score -1):

You are facing this problem because when you are posting your forms so after reloading your dropdown is unable to find data in viewbag. So make sure that code you are using in get method while retrieving your data from db or from static list, copy paste that code into post verb as well..

Happy Coding :)