# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key "Auteur_du_Livre"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

(First topic for me -> Amazing !) 
I'm actually learning how to Handle ASP.NET MVC and i'm having some problem with he Html Helper DropDownListFor.

So the class concerned looks like that :

```
public class Auteur {
   [required]
   public int Id {get; set;} 
   public string Nom {get; set;}
}
```

My controller looks like that :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Ajout_livre()
{
   Donnee_a_persister data = new Donnee_a_persister();
   List<Auteur> auteur_possible = new List<Auteur>();
   foreach (Auteur temp in data.afficher_auteurs())
      auteur_possible.Add(temp);
   ViewBag.auteur_possible = new SelectList(auteur_possible,"Id","Nom");
   return View();
}
```

And I use it in my view like that :

```
<div>
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Auteur_du_livre)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Auteur_du_livre, (SelectList)ViewBag.auteur_possible)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auteur_du_livre)
</div>
```

Here is my post-method (as you can see i tried to populate the select list here too)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Ajout_livre(Livre detaillivreaajouter)
{
   Donnee_a_persister data = new Donnee_a_persister();
   List<Auteur> auteur_possible = new List<Auteur>();
   foreach (Auteur temp in data.afficher_auteurs())
      auteur_possible.Add(temp);
   ViewBag.auteur_possible = new SelectList(auteur_possible, "Id", "Nom");
   if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
   {
      return View(detaillivreaajouter);
   }

   //Work out
   return View("Livre_eligible", detaillivreaajouter);
}
```

`Auteur_du_livre reffers` to a variable of type `Auteur` as this view is strongly typed.
So I get the view and my dropdown list is populated with the content of the `ViewBag` but when I submit the form I get the following error

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key "Auteur_du_Livre"

I've seen that this problem is frequent so i've tried a lot of thing but i can't figure out what is really happening

**Is it possible to get the whole object directly from the form(due to the binding) or do I have to get the property Id and find the corresponding Object in my post method ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key "key"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916642/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)

Comment: you need to populate the ``ViewBag.auteur_possible`` post action as well

Comment: Thanks for the help Ehsan but it still doesn't work and my case is different compared to what've seen in the possible duplicate topic.

Comment: have you handled it in post action?

Comment: Yes i tried. I will edit the topic with the post method.

Comment: I updated my question though :) .

Comment: The error means that `ViewBag.auteur_possible` is null. Are you sure `ModelState` is invalid and your returning the same view. I suspect you actually hitting `return View("Livre_eligible", detaillivreaajouter);` and its that view which is causing the error. (but why are you doing it that way instead or redirecting anyway?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585495/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get what's wrong in my Model : i thought that the binding made with the SelectList could directly get the object of type Auteur when the user submit the form but **it's wrong**. 
 The binding can only get a primitive variable (here it would get the property Id of type int) that was assert on the value fo the form via the selectlist. 
Thanks for all.
So i've just changed the helper in my view in the following way :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Auteur_du_livre.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.auteur_possible)
```