# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DiseaseType'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to bind data to dropdownlist, select one and save it into database.
I've successfully binded data to dropdownlist but it is giving an error

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DiseaseType'.
```

on click of save button.

**Edit.cshtml code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DiseaseType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DiseaseType, ViewData["Diseases"] as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DiseaseType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**PatientController.cs code:**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
        List<string> disease = new List<string>();
        disease.Add("Select");
        disease.Add("Cancer");
        disease.Add("Heart");
        SelectList Diseases = new SelectList(disease);
        ViewBag.Diseases = Diseases;

        PatientDBHandle pdb = new PatientDBHandle();
        return View(pdb.GetPatient().Find(p => p.ID == id));
}
```

**Patient.cs class:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please select Disease Type.")]
public string DiseaseType { get; set; }
```

**PatientDBHandle.cs code:**

```
public bool UpdatePatient(Patient patient)
{
    connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdatePatientDetails", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", patient.ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DiseaseType", patient.DiseaseType);

    con.Open();
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    if(i >= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've created one table Patient

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patient] (
[ID]          INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[DiseaseType] VARCHAR (20)    NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

I'm new to mvc, please help.

Comment: Can you post the `Edit` method that returns the ViewModel?

Comment: @jom Now check the code

Comment: What is the data type of this property `DiseaseType` in the view, `model.DiseaseType`? Is it `int` or `string`? Please also add this class in here...

Comment: @jom string, check the code now

Comment: I'm testing this in my local and am not seeing the problem, where exactly does this issue occur?

Comment: @jom it is throwing an error while saving

Comment: Then we're gonna need to see the `POST` method of this `Edit` (or whatever you're using for saving) method as well.

Comment: You seem to be doing it right already. Are you sure this error message occurred while saving? Or [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26585831/3634538) and see if it helps.

Comment: [This post](/a/41842488/3634538) is also good, make sure the property is not null while binding.

Comment: You know `ViewBag` and `ViewData` are not the same thing? I don' t know about the rest of the code but i think: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DiseaseType, ViewData["Diseases"] as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })` should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DiseaseType, ViewBag.Diseases as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `List<string>` and `SelectList` in your controller, use a `List<SelectListItem>` instead and load that into your `ViewBag`:

```
List<SelectListItem> disease = new List<SelectListItem>();

        disease.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Select", Text = "Select" });
        disease.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Cancer", Text = "Cancer" });
        disease.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Heart", Text = "Heart" });

        ViewBag.Diseases = disease;
```

In your View (Edit.cshtml) use your `ViewBag` for the dropdown like so:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DiseaseType", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Diseases, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Here I have put "DiseaseType" in instead of your model, but only to demonstrate that when you then post your choice, in order to get that value passed back into your controller, take a string called DiseaseType (use your model instead):

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult TestStack(string DiseaseType)
    {
        string result = DiseaseType;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: It is working fine in Edit but I tried same code in with Create and it is giving same error again in Create. What can be the issue?

Comment: That's hard to say without seeing your code. Are you using the ViewBag.Something = populated List<SelectListItem> and do you cast it in your view? (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Something. Also, do you pass the correct/same model from your view to your controller?