# Keep data in ViewModel when validating in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

In my asp.NET MVC5 app I have a controller that supplies a view which is strongly typed vs a viewmodel. This viewmodel has a `SelectList` property (among others), and the controller supplies the data on creation from the database:

```
public ActionResult Simulation() {
    var SimVM = new SimulationVM(
        StrategyRepository.GetStrategies().Select(n => n.Name), 
    );
    return View(SimVM);
}
```

The `SelectList` is then used as data source for a `DropDown` choice in a form. The `HttpPost` method does some datavalidation, i.e.,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Simulation(SimulationVM _simVM) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        // ...
    }        
    else return View(_simVM);
}
```

So with the code above, the `DropDown` data is empty, since on posting, the `SimulationVM` object is created new. The usual trick of using `Html.HiddenFor` does not work on collections.

Of course, I could go back and fetch the data again from the database, but that seems to be bad, a database fetch for such a simple thing as a validation where I know the data hasn't changed.

What is the best (or for the sake of not being subjective: any) way to keep some data in the `ViewModel` (or repopulate it efficiently)?

Comment: You should go back and fetch the data for the `SelectList` again from the database. Why do you think that's bad?

Comment: You could cache the selectlist if you feel that performance is an issue: [stackoverflow.com/questions/18703958/persist-selectlist-in-model-on-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703958/persist-selectlist-in-model-on-post)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: I always had the impression one should minimize database fetches for performance reasons. This seems unnecessary here since the data should not change between validations.

Comment: The other options would be to render hidden controls for the properties of the collection which would be really bad for performance. If you include client side validation, then its rare you would ever need to return the view anyway, but you can always cache the collection if you concerned with hitting the database.

Comment: @ToaoG, why don't you use ajax calls for any calls to post? I would say something like Knockoutjs always helps a lot ... that way you don't really have to fetch anything back as it is already there... the other would be to cache it, but a long list of strings would probably  more costly than retrieving it back from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a requrement that you not go back to the database and you're 100% confident that the data will not change (i.e. this is a list of states as opposed to a list of orders or something) then you can add the collection to a session variable. Here's a link to a decent article:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-and-access-447ada98

That being said, I usually just go to the database and get the data again. If doing so for a second time is causing huge performance issues, it is most likely causing performance issues the first time and you should treat the problem rather than the symptom.